# Django Rest Framework: Convert serialized data to list of values

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using a DRF ModelSerializer to serve a one-field queryset, but the response returns as a list of dicts

> [{"state": "AL"}, {"state": "AR"}, {"state": "AZ"}]

Is there any way to return a pure string list, like ["AL", "AR", "AZ"] ? I've explored other questions, but haven't found anything useful.

Comment: Wouldn't a [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) work?

Comment: you can use python comprehension list to transform your dict to list of values and return it  as json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the state, you can extract the data out of that list of dicts:

```
response = [{"state": "AL"}, {"state": "AR"}, {"state": "AZ"}]
states = [data.get("state") for data in response]
print(states)
```

**Output**

```
['AL', 'AR', 'AZ']
```